# Get a sub-list of string matching a list of word

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>() 
 { 
      "This is a first matching exemple", 
      "This is second matching exemple", 
      "this one don't match", 
      "Here, the last item" 
 };

 List<string> words = new List<string>() { "This", "is" };
```

How can i get a list matching all the words

```
List<string> result = myList.Contains(AllWords???);
```

Edit 1 : I have forgotten to specify that words don't have to be completely matched.

Thus :

```
 List<string> words = new List<string>() { "This", "i" }
```

for exemple must return the same result.

Edit 2 : After reading some answers (chomba code exemple), i updated my code to :

```
List<string> _list = new List<string>();
// Populated from factory.
_list = SQLFactory  .GetDataView("Provider")
                    .ToTable()
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(r => r[1].ToString())
                    .ToList<string>();

// Construct list of word from textbox.
List<string> words = txtName.Text.ToLower().Split(' ').ToList();

// Update ListView
ListView.ListViewItemCollection lvic = new ListView.ListViewItemCollection(lvName);
lvName.BeginUpdate();
lvName.Items.Clear();
lvic.AddRange(_list .AsParallel()
                    .Where(x => words.All(word => x.Contains(word)))
                        .AsParallel()
                        .Select(t => new ListViewItem(t))
                        .ToList()
                        .ToArray());
lvName.EndUpdate();
```

But resulting listview still miss some items.
[image: First search]

[image: Second search]

Edit 3: Problem solved. I just have to manage the case of words.

```
lvic.AddRange(_list .AsParallel()
                    .Where(x => words.All(word => x.Contains(word)))
                        .AsParallel()
                        .Select(t => new ListViewItem(t))
                        .ToList()
                        .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<string> result = myList.Where(x => !words.Except(x.Split(' ')).Any()).ToList();
```

or if you don't need words to be completely matched:

```
List<string> result = myList.Where(x => words.All(word => x.Contains(word))).ToList();
```

Comment: Some issues with bigger list. Sometimes it excludes results.

Comment: I've found my mistake. I've forgotten to 'lowercase' words.

Comment: @LaurentKIELISZAK Don't forget to accept the answer that solves your problem.

Comment: just did (check th mark on the left ? Sorry, but i'm a newbie here).

Answer (score 1):

There might be a bit more efficient way of doing this but, this comes to mind at the moment:

```
 var result = (from sentence in myList let wordsArray = sentence.Split(' ').ToList() 
               where wordsArray.Intersect(words).Count() == words.Count 
               select sentence).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    myList.add("This is a first matching exemple"); 
    myList.add("This is second matching exemple"); 
            myList.add( "this one don't match"); 
                    myList.add("Here, the last item"); 


         List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
         words.add("This");
         words.add("is");
         List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
String text = words.get(0)+" "+words.get(1);
Iterator it = myList.iterator();
Iterator it1 = words.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
String x =  (String) it.next();
if(x.contains(text)){
    newList.add(x);
}

}
System.out.println(newList);
```

Comment: I was expecting a one (or two) line command. I already know how to iterate thru a list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution. I've added some parallel syntax to speed execution.

lvName is a listview.

txtName is a text box to find matching words (separate with spaces).

DataView _view is initialized with a query possessing 2 columns at least. Column number 2 is the string we are searching for.

```
DataView _view = GettingDataFromFunctionCall();
List<string> _list = new List<string>();
// Populated from factory.
_list = _view.ToTable()
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(row => row[1].ToString())
             .ToList<string>();

// Construct list of word from textbox.
List<string> words = txtName.Text.ToLower().Split(' ').ToList();

// Update ListView
ListView.ListViewItemCollection lvic = new ListView.ListViewItemCollection(lvName);
lvName.BeginUpdate();
lvName.Items.Clear();
lvic.AddRange(_list .AsParallel()
                .Where(x => words.All(word => x.ToLower().Contains(word)))
                    .AsParallel()
                    .Select(t => new ListViewItem(t))
                    .ToList()
                    .ToArray());
lvName.EndUpdate();
```